# trying to see if selected item is linking to new page so that if it is I can add an icon

Tags: php, drupal, twig

In my twig file I am trying to see if target = '_blank' is selected in my Drupal file and if so add an icon.

I keep running into an error whenever I run this:

```
{% if item.url.getOption('attributes')['target'] == "_blank" %}
  <span class="site-menu__link--external">
    {% include directory ~ '/templates/images/icons/email.svg' %}
  </span>
{% endif %}
```

It seems there is an error with me adding "_blank" instead of "blank" because when I add "blank" there are no errors. But I need "_blank"

Comment: Do you think it might be a good idea to tell us exactly what error you're getting...?

Comment: Just says 'The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.'

Answer (score 0):

So I found another way to solve the problem. I added this code and then used the added class to add the icon in css.

```
 {% if item.url.options.attributes.target == '_blank' %}
     {% set link_classes = link_classes|merge(['site-menu__link-external']) %}
 {% endif %}
```